# sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats doesn't work fine with filtered indexes

Tags: indexing, usage-statistics, filtered-index

I have a SQL Server with 11.0.6020.0 compilation.

I have a stored procedure with a select. When I execute the procedure in SSMS the execution plan shows that a filtered index is used, and the sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats system view immediately reflects it (user seek is increased).

But when the procedure is executed from an application, the sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats doesn't reflect the execution (user seek for the index remains and doesn't increase).

Somebody has observed this behaviour and could explain it?